# Private Domain and SAP

Tags: marketing-cloud, deliverability, sender-authentication-package

When we have in the same BU one SAP and several additional private domains registered, the emails that are sent from the private domains (different from the SAP domain) will be branded by the SAP or only the emails sent through the domain registered with the SAP will be branded?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Key differences between these two:

- An SAP domain includes link-wrapping (i.e. links, images, and anything else that would normally reflect Salesforce Marketing Cloud, will reflect the chosen SAP domain instead).  The domain is also authenticated with SPF/Sender ID and DKIM/Domain Keys.
- A Private Domain this is an authenticated domain for use in the From address only.  It is set up either via a User or Sender Profile, and this type of Private Domain DOES NOT include link-wrapping.  It has an MX record, SPF/Sender ID and DKIM/Domain Keys.

The difference is, that while you can have as many Private Domains on each BU, you are limited only to one SAP. Hence your links and images will still reflect your SAP despite emails being sent from one of the additional Private Domains.

Comment: Thanks Lukas. That was my initial though but Marketing Cloud support provide me a different reply, maybe my question was not clear enough...

Comment: SAP and PD is not always easy to comprehend, and it took me a while to get a complete understanding. I should soon write an article on the topic :-)