# Register and configure settings of a new domain that doesn't relate to our SAP purchased domain

Tags: marketing-cloud, email-studio

We have purchased SAP with thecompany.com domain configured by Salesforce.

The client requested to send the emails from a different domain flowersflowers.com (that is completely different from ours)

Is it possible to configure Email Security settings (TLS, DKIM, SPF, DomainKeys etc), change RMM with this new domain? If so, how they should be configured?

As I understand, image and Subscription Center/Profile Center URLs can’t be changed. Will we face the fact that emails end up in spam? Does it not contradict the CAN-SPAM Rule?

There is an option “Register Domain” in Marketing Cloud by adding a token in DNS records of a domain. Is it possible to use this feature to send emails from flowersflowers.com? If so, the answers to the questions above are interested.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SAP is a package of features. One of those features is authenticated sending of emails. Others are image branding, link branding, a dedicated IP, RMM....

If you expect all the behaviors of an SAP - you need an SAP. With another SAP however, you need another BU, as there is only one SAP per BU configurable.

So - You either:

- change your existing SAP (i think that comes at the cost of a new SAP after a 30 day period or so). Of course, losing the capabilities on your already configured one, but staying in the "one BU one SAP" boundaries.
- buy a new business unit, buy a new SAP that packages all the features, link branding, authenticated emails. Of course, this is not realistic in a post-implementation scenario, as the costs of BUs are no fun, let alone the conceptual and implementation effort.
- For your existing BU, you buy a Private Domain (that is an SF product name) for sending only, which does only one part of the SAP package, namely setup a verified sender domain (DKIM, SPF) without the "other" features like image, link branding, dedicated IP, RMM.
  So it has limits. But it solves the main problem, sending as a different domain. Hence this is likely your go-to option.

In contrast to SAPs, you can have multiple private domains on an existing BU with SAP configured, they then become choices when setting up Sender Profiles. Of course, those Private Domains have to be delegated by the client again, as with SAP.

- You want images that are hosted on https. So your image domain should have an SSL certificate. From a deliverability point of view, you can host images elsewhere than your SAP / SSL'ed Business Unit.
- your links, including subscription center and unsubscription, can point anywhere without affecting deliverability. Again, https is something you want.

Additional reading: [Customer wants to use a new sending domain but with the same IP - will this require an additional SAP package?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/339951/customer-wants-to-use-a-new-sending-domain-but-with-the-same-ip-will-this-requ)

[Private Domain and SAP](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/275586/private-domain-and-sap)

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000318538&type=1&mode=1

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can I add our new purchased domain through Setup -> Feature Setting -> Email Studio -> From Email Addresses as described here https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.mc_es_register_a_domain.htm&type=5 ? Or do I need to purchase a Private Domain as described here https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000318538&type=1&mode=1 ? What is the difference between these 2 options?

Comment: A From Email _address_ has to be under a previously purchased authenticated _domain_, from either Private Domain or SAP.  You cannot add domains in the frontend.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So, if we had bought a domain in GoDaddy, we can't simply add it in the frontend. A Private Domain product needs to be purchased. Correct?

Comment: pls check the last point here, you can be the owner of the domain.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000318538&type=1&mode=1 
From here on it makes sense for you to involve Salesforce Support, they will have the official material.